# How to make Spring Webflow return one of more than 2 events

Tags: spring-webflow

I would like to return one of the possible 3 events from my action class. Most of the Spring Webflow events are binary as in they return `success()` / `error()` or `yes()` / `no()` types of events. I would like to return `success()` , `error()` and `someThingElse()` or some String events like `approved`, `rejected`, `onHold`

How would I do that?

Thank you
Chaitanya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer myself! Yet again.
Here it is:

I used `Event org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.result(String eventId)` to which one can pass any fancy event names as strings and SWF detects them. Voila.